# What are the smooth, compact hypersurfaces of the euclidean space whose interior is contractible?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $S$ be a smooth, compact hypersurface (without boundary) of the euclidean space $\mathbb R^N$. In addition assume that the interior region of $S$ ( i.e., the bounded connected component of $\mathbb R^N\backslash S$ ) is contractible. Does it imply that $S$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere?

Of course, this is true for $N=2$. I do not know whether it still holds in higher dimensions $N\geq 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To supplement Igor's answer regarding the situation in dimensions $\ne 4$:

In general, if $X$ is a compact contractible $n$-dimensional manifold, then the boundary $\partial X$ of $X$ is an *[(integer) homology sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere)*, meaning that $H_*(\partial X)\cong H_*(S^{n-1})$. (This is an application of the Poincare duality and the long exact sequence of the pair $(X, \partial X)$.) From this, it follows that if $n\le 3$, then the boundary is homeomorphic (hence, diffeomorphic) to $S^{n-1}$, since a homology sphere of dimension $\le 2$ is homeomorphic/diffeomorphic to the ordinary sphere. On the other hand, for every $k\ge 3$ there are many smooth closed $k$-dimensional manifolds which are homology spheres but are not even homotopy-equivalent to spheres since they are not simply-connected (see for instance Theorem in in Kervaire's paper below). The first such example was discovered by Poincare (for $k=3$) and is called the *Poincare homology sphere.*

Hence, it is reasonable to ask for the converse: "Does every $k$-dimensional homology sphere $M$ bound a compact contractible manifold?" (I am intentionally sloppy about the category in which one is working: smooth or topological manifolds.)

It turns out that if $k\ge 4$ then the answer to this question is positive in the following sense:

Every smooth $k$-dimensional homology sphere is homeomorphic to the boundary of a smooth compact contractible $k+1$-dimensional manifold.

This result is mostly due to Michael Kervaire, Theorem 3 in:

*Kervaire, Michel A.*, [**Smooth homology spheres and their fundamental groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1995269), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 144, 67-72 (1969). [ZBL0187.20401](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0187.20401).

(See also the Wikipedia article linked by Igor.)

For $k=3$ the situation is much more subtle and I will not discuss it (see Igor's answer).

Now, how is it related to your question? Suppose that $X$ is a smooth compact contractible $n$-dimensional manifold, $n\ne 4$. Then *double* $X$ across its boundary, by gluing another copy of $X$. After "smoothing the corners" the double $DX$ is a smooth manifold containing a diffeomorphic copy of $X$. It is easy to see that $X$ is simply-connected (Seifert-van Kampen's theorem) and is an $n$-dimensional homology sphere (Mayer-Vietoris theorem), and, after some fiddling, can be shown to be diffeomorphic to the standard sphere $S^n$ (this is an application of the h-cobordism theorem if $n\ge 6$ and some work of Milnor if $n=5$). By applying this diffeomorphism $f: DX\to S^n$, we, thus, obtain a smooth embedding
$$
\partial X\to X \to DX \stackrel{f}{\to} S^n
$$
of our homology sphere $\partial X$ to $S^n$ so that the image bounds the  contractible domain $f(X)$.

So, when all this is said and done, we conclude that for each $n\ge 5$, there exist smooth submanifolds $M\subset S^n$ which bound contractible domains in $S^n$, but $M$ is not even homotopy-equivalent to $S^{n-1}$. For $n=4$, the conclusion is the same but the proof is a bit more ad hoc (this is where Mazur manifolds show up).

Answer (score 2):

No. See [the Wikipedia article on Mazur manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur_manifold) for more.

Comment: But is a Mazur manifold embedding in $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: @TedShifrin you did not read the article carefully.

Comment: @TedShifrin If you had, you would have seen: An observation of Mazur's shows that the double of such manifolds is diffeomorphic to $S^$  #with the standard smooth structure.

Comment: I am not a topologist by training, so I do not see immediately how this is relevant. Perhaps the OP does not understand either how you have answered his question.

Comment: @TedShifrin The quote says precisely that the mazur manifolds are smooth submanifolds with boundary of $\mathbb{R}^4$ I am not sure what I can add.

Comment: You may want to add that similar examples exist in all dimensions $\ge 4$.